# typescript IntelliSense not worked in my vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015)

Version: 1.42.1
Commit: c47d83b293181d9be64f27ff093689e8e7aed054
Date: 2020-02-11T14:44:27.652Z
Electron: 6.1.6
Chrome: 76.0.3809.146
Node.js: 12.4.0
V8: 7.6.303.31-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 17.7.0

Tried some method online but it's not worked. 
There's no hover infomation on the ts Type, and no IntelliSense when I type `object.`.

And my win10 works fine.

I ran vscode with `code . --disable-extensions`, not worked.
I ran `npm i typescript -g` and the console output `Version 3.8.3` when I execute `tsc --version`.

I installed `JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly` extention, but I could not see the `TypeScript: Select TypeScript version` command in the vs code command palette.

I tried install vs code 1.40.2, it's not worked too.

no typescript version info in the vscode status bar:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "Tried some method online but it's not worked."? It is not really clear, what your actual problem ist. Did you install the typescript package (`npm i typescript --save-dev')?

Comment: @JohnArcher I am sorry. And I add more detail in the description.

Comment: It sounds like you may have disabled the built-in `JavaScript and TypeScript language features` extension. Search `@builtin` in the VS Code extensions view to check this

Comment: @MattBierner Thanks. I got it.